# spring-webflux url redirect and static html and rest api routing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I need the restful api under "`/api/*`" using authorization, all other routing like "`/`" and "`/**`" url goes to "`/resources/static/index.html`" without authorization. (the index.html used polymer to handle routing).

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: are you using the WebFlux annotation model or the functional? Can you post some code to show what you've been trying?

Answer (score 1):

last edit: added ".httpBasic().and().formLogin().and()", it worked for "/api/**" authorization. but there's still problem while visiting "http://127.0.0.1:8080/template-one/gzgg" which I intent it would redirect to "http://127.0.0.1:8080".

I tried using

```
@Bean
public MapReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsRepository() {
    UserDetails admin = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("admin").password("123").roles("ADMIN").build();
    UserDetails santiago = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("santiago").password("456").roles("USER").build();
    return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(admin,santiago);
}

@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
            .authorizeExchange()
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/**").hasRole("ADMIN")

            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").permitAll()
            //.pathMatchers("/users/{user}/**").access(this::currentUserMatchesPath)
            .anyExchange().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic().and()
            .formLogin().and()
            .build();
}
```

and

```
@Configuration
public class GlobalRouter {

@Bean
RouterFunction<?> routerFunction() {
    RouterFunction router = resources("/**", new ClassPathResource("static/"));
    return router;

  }
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class CustomWebFilter implements WebFilter {
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    if (exchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath().equals("/")) {
        return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(exchange.getRequest().mutate().path("/index.html").build()).build());
    }

    return chain.filter(exchange);
}
}
```

It's OK to visit "resources/static/index.html", but while visiting "http://localhost:8080/api/person/all", I enter "admin"/"123" for authrization, but authrization failed.